# How do you convert a String array to an Int Array - Swift5

Tags: swift

### I'm having issues with this code:

```
var overwriteArray2: [Int] = Int(overwriteArray)
```

This is the error I'm getting

> No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: What is `overwriteArray`? is it an array of `String`s, i.e. `[String]`?

Comment: Yes! it's a [String], it contains an array for UserDefaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through each element and convert it. Better would be to use `compactMap`.

```
func example(textArray: [String]) -> [Int] {
    textArray.compactMap { Int($0) }
}
```